# Is there a way to update a notification sent by Firebase Cloud Message (FCM) to an web app instead of creating a new one?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM for a chat app. Everytime an user receives a message, I send him a notification via FCM. If user isn't with my web app in foreground, the message handling happens in a default Service Worker that generates a notification with the parameters I've specified on the body of my request. The problem is, everytime a new push message is sent and the app is in background, browsers (tested on Chrome and Firefox) are creating a new message instead of updating the existing one. I would like to keep the already visible notification and only update its value, is that possible?

### Service Worker that handles the push if app isn't in foreground:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': '*****'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

### JSON body of the request sent to FCM server

```
{
    "priority" : "normal",
    "collapse_key": "demo",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Felicius Humble",
        "body": "This is a sample message content",
        "click_action": "https://****.herokuapp.com",
        "icon": "****"
    },
    "to": "****",
    "data": {
        "id": 7,
        "timestamp": 1493573846692,
        "content": "teste",
        "type": "MESSAGE",
        "direction": "OUTPUT",
        "sender": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Felicius Humble",
            "email": "****@gmail.com",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "picture": "****",
            "facebookID": "****",
            "fcmToken": "****",
            "accessToken": "****"
        },
        "chatID": 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so I've found [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) that shows all options available for the json body. For what I need I just need to add "tag" param on notification obj in my json body. **If you want to update the notification, sent it with the same tag**. Example:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "",
        "body": "",
        "click_action": "",
        "icon": "",
        "tag" : "this must be the same for the notifications you want to update"
    },
    "to": "****",
    "data": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to hear that you found the relevant documentation. Instead of just linking to the documentation (which might change over time), can you include the minimal relevant information in the answer itself?

Comment: This is supported only on android any idea about iOS?

Comment: @humnle-student This is supported only on android any idea about iOS?

Answer (score 0):

There are scenarios where you might want a replacing notification to notify the user rather than silently update. Chat applications are a good example. In this case you should set `tag` and `renotify` to true.

write this code on your `sw.js`

```
    const title = 'Notification 2 of 2';
    const options = {
      tag: 'renotify',
      renotify: true
    };
    registration.showNotification(title, options);
```

> You can test demo on [here](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/) by clicking in `renotify` button

Comment: `renotify` is not documented. Where did you get it?

Comment: `renotify` is documented as part of WebpushNotification. It's mentioned under several sections https://firebase.google.com/s/results/?q=renotify

Comment: @AndreyGordeev It's not renotify it's tag attribute